# What are the lyrics?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

As a beginner, I cannot understand the conversation in [`R. City - Locked Away` music video](https://youtu.be/6GUm5g8SG4o?t=1m47s) at 1m 46s. It sounds like "very American" English.

I googled it, but it is not part of the song and I could not find any transcription.

Could you transcript it please ?

EDIT: I especially wonder if he is saying `man` or `ma'am`.

Comment: Can you at least write what you have been able to understand, and place a _______ for the part you can't.

Comment: "And here you are yelling at me man" appears to be the bit you were struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full transcript of the conversation from the point I was able to hear distinct words:

> (man)...sitting around all day playing video games, yo?  I'm out there on these streets trying to figure things out and here you are yelling at me man, come on man don't do me like that man like I really out there tryin'.
>
> (woman) How are you gonna get pay what is your plan?
>
> (man) I tryin', I have a plan you just need to trust me man.